# Issue while compiling gcc-5.2.0

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, raspbian, linux-from-scratch

I am trying to build my own lfs system for Raspberry PI 2.

As a part of it I am trying to compile gcc on Raspberry PI 2, with raspbian as a base operating system.

I could build the binutils using the instructions on lfs development version. But while compiling gcc I am getting below error

```
g++ -c   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/. -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../include -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libcpp/include -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./gmp -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/gmp -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./mpfr/src -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/mpfr/src -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/mpc/src  -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o except.o -MT except.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/except.TPo ../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/except.c   
g++ -c   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/. -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../include -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libcpp/include -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./gmp -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/gmp -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./mpfr/src -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/mpfr/src -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/mpc/src  -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o explow.o -MT explow.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/explow.TPo ../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/explow.c   
g++ -c   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/. -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../include -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libcpp/include -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./gmp -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/gmp -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./mpfr/src -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/mpfr/src -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/mpc/src  -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o expmed.o -MT expmed.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/expmed.TPo ../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/expmed.c   
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/wide-int.h: In function 'long long unsigned int choose_multiplier(long long unsigned int, int, int, long long unsigned int*, int*, int*)':                                               
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/wide-int.h:798:57: warning: array subscript is below array bounds [-Warray-bounds]                                                                                                       
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/wide-int.h:798:57: warning: array subscript is below array bounds [-Warray-bounds]                                                                                                       
g++ -c   -g -O2 -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/. -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../include -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libcpp/include -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./gmp -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/gmp -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/./mpfr/src -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/mpfr/src -I/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-5.2.0/mpc/src  -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/../libbacktrace   -o expr.o -MT expr.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/expr.TPo ../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/expr.c           
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/expr.c: In function 'void store_constructor(tree, rtx, int, long long int)':                                                                                                             
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/expr.c:6529:1: internal compiler error: output_operand: invalid shift operand                                                                                                            
Please submit a full bug report,                                                                                                                                                                             
with preprocessed source if appropriate.                                                                                                                                                                     
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.                                                                                                                                            
Preprocessed source stored into /tmp/ccAUc9Pu.out file, please attach this to your bugreport.                                                                                                                
Makefile:1065: recipe for target 'expr.o' failed                                                                                                                                                             
make[2]: *** [expr.o] Error 1                                                                                                                                                                                
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build/gcc'                                                                                                                                                  
Makefile:4105: recipe for target 'all-gcc' failed                                                                                                                                                            
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2                                                                                                                                                                               
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/gcc-build'                                                                                                                                                      
Makefile:858: recipe for target 'all' failed                                                                                                                                                                 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to trace the cause of error by looking at the expr.c file, but could not find issue. I have uploaded the "/tmp/ccAUc9Pu.out" to http://turl.ca/dcfansr

Can someone please help me how to debug the exact cause of issue

Comment: Did you submit a bug report to gcc?

Comment: Perhaps try the latest 5.2 snapshot, ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/snapshots/LATEST-5

Comment: I have reported the bug:- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67919

Comment: @teppic: I have tried the snapshot but unfortunately snapshot has the same issue. looks like its the real bug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after checking all the system requirements were installed by running the version check at http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable-systemd/prologue/hostreqs.html and rebooting the system it worked afterwards.